# Calling a activity method from a BroadCast Receiver

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I am looking around on how to call a method which is there in an `AbstractActivity` from a `BroadCast Receiver`. I tried making the method static and calling it straight away from the broadcast receiver just by using the classname. But the app then crashes with a `nullpointer exception` in the switch statement which is there in the static method.

Example:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AbstractActivity{
     Context context;
    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    public static void additionDone(Context context,int number){
    switch(number)
    case 1:
      Toast.makeText(context, "First case" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    break;

    }

 }
```

BroadCast Receiver example:

```
public class receiver extends BroadcastReciever{
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
//logic
}
public class anotherMethod(){
MainActivity.additionDone(1,context);

}
}
```

Is something wrong with the code above? Or is there a different way of calling a static method which belongs to a `abstract activity`?

Comment: the only thing that could be null in that point is the context

Comment: here is an idea, change your line  Toast.makeText(context, "First case" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  to  Log.e("yourtag", "first case"); it will pass so check your context passing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Context context;` of the `MainActivity`  is never assigned,

change your code to this

```
public static void additionDone(int number, Context context){
     ...//work with that context
}
```

and in your reciever

```
MainActivity.additionDone(1, context); //call with the context you got in your receiver constructor
```

Comment: the context is there in additionDone.. i missed it somehow.. edited the question..that is not the issue

Comment: you are still missing it in the calling line too though : MainActivity.additionDone(1, context);

Comment: ohh wow. the context was null all this while. That was a stupid question from me. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The order of the parameters/arguments don't match.

`additionDone(Context context,int number)`

`MainActivity.additionDone(1,context)`